# Why (referenceTos[0] != null) check is being performed in following code?

Tags: sobject, fields, java

I was going through a salesforce.com developer documentation

[code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm)

```
// Iterate through the list of describe sObject results
for (int i=0;i < describeSObjectResults.length; i++)
{
    DescribeSObjectResult desObj = describeSObjectResults[i];
    // Get the name of the sObject
    String objectName = desObj.getName();
    System.out.println("sObject name: " + objectName);

    // For each described sObject, get the fields
    Field[] fields = desObj.getFields();

    // Get some other properties
    if (desObj.getActivateable()) System.out.println("\tActivateable");

    // Iterate through the fields to get properties for each field
    for(int j=0;j < fields.length; j++)
    {                        
        Field field = fields[j];
        System.out.println("\tField: " + field.getName());
        System.out.println("\t\tLabel: " + field.getLabel());
        if (field.isCustom()) 
            System.out.println("\t\tThis is a custom field.");
        System.out.println("\t\tType: " + field.getType());
        if (field.getLength() > 0)
            System.out.println("\t\tLength: " + field.getLength());
        if (field.getPrecision() > 0)
            System.out.println("\t\tPrecision: " + field.getPrecision());

        // Determine whether this is a picklist field
        if (field.getType() == FieldType.picklist)
        {                            
            // Determine whether there are picklist values
            PicklistEntry[] picklistValues = field.getPicklistValues();
            if (picklistValues != null && picklistValues[0] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("\t\tPicklist values = ");
                for (int k = 0; k < picklistValues.length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\tItem: " + picklistValues[k].getLabel());
                }
            }
        }

        // Determine whether this is a reference field
        if (field.getType() == FieldType.reference)
        {                            
            // Determine whether this field refers to another object
            String[] referenceTos = field.getReferenceTo();
            if (referenceTos != null && referenceTos[0] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("\t\tField references the following objects:");
                for (int k = 0; k < referenceTos.length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + referenceTos[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is just overzealous null checking. Null pointer exceptions are one of the most common errors thrown by code, so many people check for nulls prior to doing anything. It is possible to have a null in referenceTos[0] even if referenceTos is not null:

```
String[] referenceTos = new String[]{};
referenceTos.add(null);
referenceTos.add('Something');
System.assertNotEquals(null, referenceTos);
System.assertEquals(null, referenceTos[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting :)

It might be something "lost in translation" - related to how results of a describe call arrive in Java. I mean that this won't even compile in Apex as the result of `field.getReferenceTo()` is `List<Schema.sObjectType>` and not `String[]`.

Some relationship names are unknown but I've never seen an unknown object!
(for example on Events you can query "down": `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM RecurringEvents) FROM Event` but not "up": `SELECT RecurrenceActivityId, RecurrenceActivity.Id FROM Event`)

Another option that comes to mind is that maybe "*you know a lookup field is here but no idea to what it points to*". maybe if somebody in your org would make a custom lookup to an object in managed package and you wouldn't have a license to work with that package?